# ng-if without breaking stylesheet?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to use an ng-if directive without adding a containing element?  I'm playing around with dynamic menu items placed by the current view controller and want to handle a dropdown type and non dropdown type, however the ng-if has to be in some kind of element which breaks the bootstrap css.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in dynNavList">

   <div ng-if="item.dd" ><!--There will be more stuff in here-->
     <a href="#{{item.url}}">Dropdown test {{item.title}}</a>
    </div>

    <span ng-if="!item.dd">
      <a href="#{{item.url}}">NoDropDown {{item.title}}</a>
    </span>

 </li>
```

Any nav item created in that html above doesn't style correctly in the navbar because it's inside a div or span element so the css doesn't apply.

I do **not** want to modify the bootstrap css to get this working and I'm trying to avoid writing any custom directives if possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ng-if on the anchor directly does not work?

Comment: You need to either override the bootstrap css (copy the existing style(s) that would be applied to these links and change where they get applied) or you need to use the DOM structure it expects (the CSS depends on this as you've figured out).  This isn't really a problem to do with ng-if but just the fact that you're changing the DOM structure from what Bootstrap is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-if` directly on the anchor is fine, [demo](http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/pgGuf/).

Comment: Yes I know that but I need a block because there will be a dropdown in some cases so I would need a block with multiple elements inside it.